# Excel Macro - copy data from several cells including its header to one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have zero knowledge about Macro. Is there a kind of code I can use to copy data from several cells including its header to one cell. It looks like this:

This is the source table:

[image: This is the source table]

And this should be the output:

[image: output table]

Comment: Is the number of content rows static? Is it equal for all columns?

Comment: Hi Akina, yes it is pretty static. I'm not sure if it is equal for all columns.

Comment: *it is pretty static. I'm not sure if it is equal for all columns.* Does it mean that the whole source contains a static amount of rows (for example, 10 rows always), but some columns may contain a lot of empty cells? If so, are those empty cells at the end of table or they may posess in the start/middle of a column?

Comment: Do you want results in Column or  in a Cell ??

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **VBA code:**

```
Sub copy_range_to_cell()
  Set rng = Range("A3:C4")
  For Each Column In rng.Columns
    For Each cell In Column.Cells
      Range("E4").Value = Range("E4").Value & cell.Text & Chr(10)
    Next cell
    Range("E4").Value = Range("E4").Value & Chr(10)
  Next Column
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Nice it's working,, perfect  10 ☺

Comment: Thanks simlev. This is working perfectly. How about if I have contents in row 5 and I want to copy the same headers but should only copy the contents in row 5?

Comment: Glad it helped, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353652) the answer. This further question about row 5 is not entirely clear to me, please add more details possibly accompanied by a screenshot. Consider opening a new question if applicable.